# Order by is not working in Oracle version of the trigger

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a combination of JOIN, ORDER BY and ROWNUM in a trigger that I am translating from SQL to Oracle 10.
The ORDER BY need to be removed from the script for the trigger to be created correctly, but I need it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Update_Quantity 
AFTER INSERT
ON MediaUsed
FOR EACH ROW
Begin
   UPDATE          Inventory 
   SET             Quantity = Quantity - 1 
   WHERE ID = ( SELECT IV1.ID FROM Inventory IV1
             INNER JOIN (
                        SELECT Distinct ItemNo, Item, :NEW.Plant AS Plant  FROM Inventory    
                        WHERE (Not :NEW.IsChanged = 0) AND  Inventory.ID = :NEW.ID_Inventory
                       )  IV2 ON IV1.Item = IV2.Item AND IV1.ItemNo = IV2.ItemNo AND IV1.Plant = IV2.Plant
                WHERE IV1.Quarantined = 0  AND IV1.Quantity > 0  AND IV1.ExpiryDate > SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(SYSTIMESTAMP) AND ROWNUM = 1
                ORDER BY IV1.ID
              );
End;

Warning: TRIGGER created with compilation errors.
```

I tried to wrap the query and put ORDER By outside but it didn't work. I found ROWNUM is not the best way to do it.
I found RANK() OVER as a better solution in my searches and wrote the following and still the trigger has some issue:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Update_Quantity 
AFTER INSERT
ON MediaUsed
FOR EACH ROW
Begin
   UPDATE          Inventory 
   SET             Quantity = Quantity - 1 
   WHERE ID = ( SELECT IV1.ID, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY IV1.ID) sal_rank FROM Inventory IV1
             INNER JOIN (
                        SELECT Distinct ItemNo, Item, :NEW.Plant AS Plant  FROM Inventory    
                        WHERE (Not :NEW.IsChanged = 0) AND  Inventory.ID = :NEW.ID_Inventory
                       )  IV2 ON IV1.Item = IV2.Item AND IV1.ItemNo = IV2.ItemNo AND IV1.Plant = IV2.Plant
                WHERE IV1.Quarantined = 0  AND IV1.Quantity > 0  AND IV1.ExpiryDate > SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(SYSTIMESTAMP) AND sal_rank <= 1 --ROWNUM = 1
              );
End;

Warning: TRIGGER created with compilation errors.
```

Removing ORDER BY fixes the trigger but I need it!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Update_Quantity 
AFTER INSERT
ON MediaUsed
FOR EACH ROW
Begin
   UPDATE          Inventory 
   SET             Quantity = Quantity - 1 
   WHERE ID = ( SELECT IV1.ID FROM Inventory IV1
             INNER JOIN (
                        SELECT Distinct ItemNo, Item, :NEW.Plant AS Plant  FROM Inventory    
                        WHERE (Not :NEW.IsChanged = 0) AND  Inventory.ID = :NEW.ID_Inventory
                       )  IV2 ON IV1.Item = IV2.Item AND IV1.ItemNo = IV2.ItemNo AND IV1.Plant = IV2.Plant
                WHERE IV1.Quarantined = 0  AND IV1.Quantity > 0  AND IV1.ExpiryDate > SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(SYSTIMESTAMP) AND ROWNUM = 1
                --ORDER BY IV1.ID
              );
End;

Trigger created.
```

So I need the ORDER BY and need to get the first row using that JOIN. If there is any way that I could get some more description about the issue in TOAD will be perfect as well.

Comment: @AI007 . . . You should provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic.  There may be other approaches that you are not considering.

Comment: What do you see when you look at the error messages from both failed compilation attempts? (Either use `SHOW ERRORS` in SQL*Plus or `SELECT * FROM USER_ERRORS` in Toad)

Comment: It triggers after INSERT and that JOIN returns 1 or more records that we need to update the topper record. I have no sample data, I am translating them exactly like this. Reading the scripts and translate to Oracle! Iknow!

Comment: @TadHarrison nothing from USER_ERRORS.

Comment: @Al007, that's odd. You can be sure your first two triggers aren't failing because of data errors (e.g. too many rows or something) because they had compilation errors and never were valid. *At the time of compilation* you ought to be able to see what those errors are, and that will be quite informative. `SELECT * FROM ALL_ERRORS` (or `USER_ERRORS`) ought to show something at that moment.

Comment: Why do you think you need the `ORDER BY`?  The way your query is written, if your subquery returned more than one row, your whole query would fail with `ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row`.  So an `ORDER BY` cannot possibly make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Your second trigger looks close to something that should work, but your query is returning two values into an = clause:

```
WHERE ID = ( SELECT IV1.ID, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY IV1.ID) sal_rank
```

How about pushing that down into a subquery to get just the top-ranked ID? Something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER OR1_EM.Update_Quantity 
AFTER INSERT
ON MediaUsed
FOR EACH ROW
Begin
   UPDATE          Inventory 
   SET             Quantity = Quantity - 1 
   WHERE ID = (SELECT ID
              FROM 
             ( SELECT IV1.ID, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY IV1.ID) sal_rank FROM Inventory IV1
             INNER JOIN (
                        SELECT Distinct ItemNo, Item, :NEW.Plant AS Plant  FROM Inventory    
                        WHERE (Not :NEW.IsChanged = 0) AND  Inventory.ID = :NEW.ID_Inventory
                       )  IV2 ON IV1.Item = IV2.Item AND IV1.ItemNo = IV2.ItemNo AND IV1.Plant = IV2.Plant
                WHERE IV1.Quarantined = 0  AND IV1.Quantity > 0  AND IV1.ExpiryDate > SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(SYSTIMESTAMP) AND sal_rank <= 1 --ROWNUM = 1
              )
              WHERE sal_rank = 1 );
End;
```

Also, note that RANK can return multiple rows for a given value if that subquery returns that ID multiple times. If that is possible you would need to reduce it to one row only returned into the = clause, easiest done with a MAX():

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER OR1_EM.Update_Quantity 
AFTER INSERT
ON MediaUsed
FOR EACH ROW
Begin
   UPDATE          Inventory 
   SET             Quantity = Quantity - 1 
   WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID)
              FROM 
             ( SELECT IV1.ID, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY IV1.ID) sal_rank FROM Inventory IV1
             INNER JOIN (
                        SELECT Distinct ItemNo, Item, :NEW.Plant AS Plant  FROM Inventory    
                        WHERE (Not :NEW.IsChanged = 0) AND  Inventory.ID = :NEW.ID_Inventory
                       )  IV2 ON IV1.Item = IV2.Item AND IV1.ItemNo = IV2.ItemNo AND IV1.Plant = IV2.Plant
                WHERE IV1.Quarantined = 0  AND IV1.Quantity > 0  AND IV1.ExpiryDate > SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(SYSTIMESTAMP) AND sal_rank <= 1 --ROWNUM = 1
              )
              WHERE sal_rank = 1 );
End;
```

Comment: Thank you, but not working, using ROWNUM or sal_rank =1 should make the script return only one row I guess.

Comment: I hadn't noticed the "AND sal_rank <= 1 " in your original. It should be removed. As we don't know your structures or data, your best approach is probably to just first write the update statement and test it until it works with a few values (hardcode where your :NEW values get used).  You may find you get more helpful error messages this way.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I resolved the issue by wrapping the script and leaving the ROWNUM outside:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER OR1_FG.Update_Quantity 
AFTER INSERT
ON OR1_FG.MediaUsed
FOR EACH ROW
Begin
   UPDATE          OR1_FG.Inventory 
   SET             Quantity = Quantity - 1 
   WHERE ID = 
    (
     select ID from 
            (
             SELECT IV1.ID FROM OR1_FG.Inventory IV1 
             INNER JOIN (
             SELECT Distinct LotNumber, Item, :NEW.Plant AS Plant  
             FROM OR1_FG.Inventory WHERE (Not :NEW.IsChanged = 0
             ) 
             AND  OR1_FG.Inventory.ID = :NEW.ID_Inventory
             )  IV2 ON IV1.Item = IV2.Item AND IV1.LotNumber = IV2.LotNumber AND IV1.Plant = IV2.Plant
                WHERE IV1.Quarantined = 0  AND IV1.Quantity > 0  AND IV1.ExpiryDate > SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(SYSTIMESTAMP) ORDER BY IV1.ID) WHERE ROWNUM = 1);
End;
```

Thank you for all contributions.